# Pyspark-Populate missing values with values other than the last known non-null value

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have data as such:

```
PeopleCountTestSchema=StructType([StructField("building",StringType(), True),
StructField("date_created",StringType(), True),
StructField("hour",StringType(), True),
StructField("wirelesscount",StringType(), True),
StructField("rundate",StringType(), True)])
```

`df=spark.read.csv("wasb://reftest@refdev.blob.core.windows.net/Praneeth/HVAC/PeopleCount_test/",schema=PeopleCountTestSchema,sep=",")
df.createOrReplaceTempView('Test')`

```
 |building date_created|hour|wirelesscount|
 +--------+------------+----+-------------+
 |36      |2017-01-02  |0   |35           |
 |36      |2017-01-03  |0   |46           |
 |36      |2017-01-04  |0   |32           |
 |36      |2017-01-05  |0   |90           |
 |36      |2017-01-06  |0   |33           |
 |36      |2017-01-07  |0   |22           |
 |36      |2017-01-08  |0   |11           |
 |36      |2017-01-09  |0   |null         |
 |36      |2017-01-10  |0   |null         |
 |36      |2017-01-11  |0   |null         |
 |36      |2017-01-12  |0   |null         |
 |36      |2017-01-13  |0   |null         |
```

this needs to be transformed into:

```
|building|date_created|hour|wirelesscount|
+--------+------------+----+-------------+
|36      |2017-01-02  |0   |35           |
|36      |2017-01-03  |0   |46           |
|36      |2017-01-04  |0   |32           |
|36      |2017-01-05  |0   |90           |
|36      |2017-01-06  |0   |33           |
|36      |2017-01-07  |0   |22           |
|36      |2017-01-08  |0   |11           |
|36      |2017-01-09  |0   |35           |
|36      |2017-01-10  |0   |46           |
|36      |2017-01-11  |0   |32           |
|36      |2017-01-12  |0   |90           |
|36      |2017-01-13  |0   |33           |
```

The current null value needs to replaced by the 7th previous value.

i tried using:

`Test2 = df.withColumn("wirelesscount2", last('wirelesscount', True).over(Window.partitionBy('building','hour').orderBy('hour').rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, -7)))`

the resulting output is

```
|building|date_created|hour|wirelesscount|rundate   |wirelesscount2|
+--------+------------+----+-------------+----------+--------------+
|36      |2017-01-02  |0   |35           |2017-04-01|null          |
|36      |2017-01-03  |0   |46           |2017-04-01|null          |
|36      |2017-01-04  |0   |32           |2017-04-01|null          |
|36      |2017-01-05  |0   |90           |2017-04-01|null          |
|36      |2017-01-06  |0   |33           |2017-04-01|null          |
|36      |2017-01-07  |0   |22           |2017-04-01|null          |
|36      |2017-01-08  |0   |11           |2017-04-01|null          |
|36      |2017-01-09  |0   |null         |2017-04-01|35            |
|36      |2017-01-10  |0   |null         |2017-04-01|46            |
|36      |2017-01-11  |0   |null         |2017-04-01|32            |
|36      |2017-01-12  |0   |null         |2017-04-01|90            |
|36      |2017-01-13  |0   |null         |2017-04-01|33            |
```

the null values are being populated with the 7th previous value but 7 of the previous values are becoming null.

Please let me know, how this can be handled.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [coalesce](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.coalesce).

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

Test2 = Test2.withColumn('wirelesscount', Test2.wirelesscount.cast('integer'))
Test2 = Test2.withColumn('wirelesscount2', Test2.wirelesscount2.cast('integer'))

test3 = Test2.withColumn('wirelesscount3', coalesce(Test2.wirelesscount, Test2.wirelesscount2))
test3.show()
```

Comment: Tried using coalesce, getting the same result, 7 previous values are still null.

Comment: coalesce does not work because your columns are StringType and nulls are actually a string written 'null'. I edited my answer